# How does the re-entrancy guard modifier work?

Tags: solidity, modifiers, reentrant-attacks

Following is code for a re-entrancy guard, but not sure if I understand it properly:

```
contract Test {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    uint256 private counter = 1;
    modifier entrancyGuard() {
        counter = counter.add(1); // counter adds 1 to the existing 1 so becomes 2
        uint256 guard = counter; // assigns 2 to the "guard" variable
        _;
        require(guard == counter, "That is not allowed"); // 2 == 2? 
    }

    function safeWithdraw(uint256 amount) external entrancyGuard() {
        // Withdraw code
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how the modifier prevents re-entrancy.

Comment: Is this from Udacity course? I had a hard time trying to wrap my head around this when i first saw this code. I tried a few dry runs and it seemed to fail.Also it would be simple to use a boolean/mutex lock sort of solution like OpenZeppelin does. @abcoathup has already put the link in answer. I would recommend to follow the solution as given in OpenZeppelin contract instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code:

```
modifier modi() {
    prolog();
    _;
    epilog();
}
function func() modi() {
    stuff();
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
function func() {
    prolog();
    stuff();
    epilog();
}
```

If `func` is re-entered (i.e., called from within the execution of `stuff`), then `prolog` is executed a second time before `epilog` was executed for the first time.

So by identifying and reverting upon a scenario in which `prolog` is executed a second time before `epilog` was executed for the first time, we can guard `func` from being re-entered.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that:

1. The counter is incremented
2. A copy of the value of counter is kept
3. Control is returned (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.8/contracts.html#function-modifiers)
4. There could be reentrancy where the counter would be incremented
5. A check is made that the copy of the counter value still equals the counter otherwise it reverts

You may want to look at the OpenZeppelin Contracts implementation:
Documentation: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/utils#ReentrancyGuard
Code: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.0.1/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol

I also suggest looking at the following post on Reentrancy: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/reentrancy-after-istanbul/1742

*Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin*

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can also ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. When there is reentrancy after the first run, does the `counter` outside of `entrancyGuard()` get reset to 1 through `uint256 private counter = 1;` and the variable `uint256 guard`, which is inside of `entrancyGuard()`, remain at 2?  The Open Zeppelin document you referred to makes more sense to me because `_notEntered = true;` is set AFTER the function in question is run, whereas my example sets counter to be equal to the guard `uint256 guard = counter;`before the function is run.

Comment: `counter` is updated to 3 when there is reentrancy whilst the original `guard` remains at 2 causing a revert.